# can find with shell expansion but not grep

Tags: cygwin

Can anyone figure out why I could not find list_awareness.html with an ls piped to a grep, yet it was findable with the shell expansion. 
I am using Cygwin on windows.

```
casper@NYKPWM2037968 /cygdrive/c/www/root
$ ls -ltr | grep list*

casper@NYKPWM2037968 /cygdrive/c/www/root
$ ls -ltr | grep list_awareness*

casper@NYKPWM2037968 /cygdrive/c/www/root
$ ls -ltr list_awareness*
-rw-rw-r--+ 1 casper Domain Users 1484 May 10  2019 list_awareness.html
-rw-rw-r--+ 1 casper Domain Users 7494 Oct 24 10:29 list_awarenessEmails.html

casper@NYKPWM2037968 /cygdrive/c/www/root
$ ls -ltr list_awarenessEmails.html
-rw-rw-r--+ 1 casper Domain Users 7494 Oct 24 10:29 list_awarenessEmails.html
```

thank you

Comment: If you just run `ls -ltr`, does it actually show up in the results?

Comment: try `ls -ltr | grep list` I suspect the `*` at the end is causing unexpected consequence due to bash argument completion